# Remove css class of all textbox inside multilevel div in jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to remove particular css class of all textbox inside 3rd level div.

```
<div class="panel panel-default" id="pnlChangeLoginInfo">
                        <div class="panel-heading">Change Login Information</div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="row">&nbsp;</div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-5">Current Password:</div>
                                <div class="col-md-7"><input class="form-control" id="txtCurPassword" name="txtCurPassword" type="password" />
                                <input class="form-control" id="hidCurPassword" name="Contact_Model.Password" type="hidden" value="irecadmin01" /></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">&nbsp;</div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-5">New Password:</div>
                                <div class="col-md-7"><input class="form-control" id="txtNewPassword" name="txtNewPassword" type="password" /></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">&nbsp;</div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-5">Repeat Password:</div>
                                <div class="col-md-7"><input class="form-control" id="txtRepPassword" name="txtRepPassword" type="password" /></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">&nbsp;</div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-5">Login Email Address:</div>
                                <div class="col-md-7"><input class="form-control" id="txtLoginEmail" name="Contact_Model.EmailAddress" type="text" value="william.robinson@irec.idaho.gov" /></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">&nbsp;</div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
```

in this html how can i remove css class "form-control" of all textbox based on div id "pnlChangeLoginInfo"

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please show some effort in solving the problem before asking others to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#pnlChangeLoginInfo > div > div > input.form-control').removeClass('form-control');
```

Please note that this example *very exactly* matches `input.form-control` elements that are *exactly* 3 levels down from the `#pnlChangeLoginInfo` element.  However, I don't see any other elements at other levels that match the `input.form-control` criteria, so you might find that the following works just as well:

```
$('#pnlChangeLoginInfo input.form-control').removeClass('form-control');
```

The advantage of the second one is that it will be more resilient to minor DOM updates in the future.

Comment: Working, I selected second option.Thanks jmar